# How to solve "Note: duplicate definition of library class"?

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard

I have `jar` libraries in folder `libs`

My `gradle` has:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
...
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
...
```

After running `release` version I have this error:

`Note: duplicate definition of program class [com.splunk.mint.ActionError]
...`

I already tried to add to proguard 
`-injars libs`
. But Issue still happens...

Comment: It seems that particular class is present in 2 or more jars... Check if you have duplicate jar files present in your libs folder...

Comment: @Codebender , no there no duplicates

Comment: That's not an error. It's just a note. If you are having problems,  then not because of that.

Comment: @XaverKapeller how to solve it?

Comment: @NickUnuchek There is nothing to solve. It is not an error. Are you actually having problems? if yes then it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @XaverKapeller but, I cant run release version, because of this issue

Comment: @NickUnuchek As I have been trying to tell you, it is not because of this issue. Whatever problems you have they are caused by something else. I assume you have problems when proguard runs? With what message is proguard failing? Is proguard outputting any errors or warnings?

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have this error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':zastavokNet:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\ProjectsHome\hd_walls\zastavokNet\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.splunk.mint\mint\4.0.8\19452a9f6424ddae60c51f97e93cb9bec3dddfd2\mint-4.0.8.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [mint-4.0.8.jar:com/splunk/mint/ActionError.class]))

Comment: @NickUnuchek Please always edit information like that into the question. Ok so you are using a library in jar form? Can you instead resolve this depedency through maven? I guess your project consits of multiple modules? Which of those modules have this library as dependency and how do those modules depend on each other? Which of them are used in your app module directly?

Comment: Please edit the question with a list of the contents of `libs/` dir and with the full dependency list.  They are repeated somewhere and need to be excluded or solely imported from gradle or libs dir